# Modifying values in json responses

Tags: node.js, json

I'm looking to modify a few values in a returning json api response that gets intercepted from the endpoint and passed through a server back to my app.

I can get it to work with changing the user part of the json response but I can't get it to include the resident part of the response

The following code changes user.require_pin and user.enable_logs from true to false. I'm looking to add resident.login_active to false from true in the same response but each time I try, I receive the error : resident: {
^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
How do I add it? Here is my current code and same json response. Thanks in advance!

```
let dat = response.data

    if(
        (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
        && (req.method === 'POST')
    ) {
        dat = {
            ...dat,
            user: {
                ...dat.user,
                require_second_pin: false,
                enable_photo_log: false
            }
            resident: {
                ...dat.resident,
                login_active: false
                }
        }
    }
```

This is a sample of the server json response

```json
{
  "token": "19f2ef14-14d7-4653-907e-1b5243900e96",
  "id": "19f2ef14-14d7-4653-907e-1b5243900e96",
  "warning": "",
  "resident": {
    "id": 18016522,
    "resident_id": 264668672,
    "name": "JOHN DOE",
    "login_active": true
  },
  "user": {
    "id": 12727533,
    "transfer_photo": false,
    "enable_log": true,
    "photo_capture_interval": 10,
    "no_of_photos": 1,
    "require_pin": true
  }
}
```

Comment: "I receive an error" -- what error? and I don't think you are yet showing the code that *isn't* working (with `login_active`)

Comment: The code I would add to that would be resident: {
                ...dat.resident,
                login_active: false,
                
            }

Comment: I added the code I would of done to include login_active.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a comma:

```
let dat = response.data

if(
  (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
    && (req.method === 'POST')
) {
  dat = {
    ...dat,
    user: {
      ...dat.user,
      require_second_pin: false,
      enable_photo_log: false
    }, // <-- this comma was missing
    resident: {
      ...dat.resident,
      login_active: false
    }
  }
}
```